# SIMD-able code?

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, avx

What is the strict definition of what code can utilise SIMD instruction set? Is it anything where you can run calculations in parallel?

So if I had:

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    sum += array[i];
}
```

this could take advantage of SIMD because we could run:

```
for(int i=0; i<100;i=i+4){
    sum0 += array[i];
    sum1 += array[i+1];
    sum2 += array[i+2];
    sum3 += array[i+3];
}

sum = sum0 + sum1 + sum2 + sum3;
```

?

Does it have to be float types, or could it be double and integer?

Comment: There isn't really any useful definition. You can use it when you can use it - it's really only answerable by experience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about x86 (SSE *et al*) then the supported types for arithmetic are 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit integers, and single and double precision floats. Note however that not all arithmetic operations are supported for all data types - SSE lacks orthogonality in this regard.

Assuming 32 bit ints and suitably aligned arrays (16 byte aligned) then you could implement your above loop example as:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>                     // SSE2 intrinsics

int32_t a[100] __attribute__ ((aligned(16)));
                                           // suitably aligned array

__m128i vsum = _mm_set1_epi32(0);          // init vsum = { 0, 0, 0, 0 }
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i += 4)
{
    __m128i v = _mm_load_si128(&a[i]);     // load 4 ints from a[i]..a[i+3]
    vsum = _mm_add_epi32(vsum, v);         // accumulate 4 partial sums
}
// final horizontal sum of partial sums
vsum = _mm_add_epi32(vsum, _mm_srli_si128(vsum, 8));
int32_t sum = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(vsum);     // sum = scalar sum of a[]
```

Comment: Thanks for this Paul. Could you just clarify something for me. With regards to alignment, is this something the SSE/AVX extension types take care for the programmer? Or is it something we have to do and if so, how is this done? I presume you are referring to padding bytes?

Comment: The basic SIMD data types (e.g. `__m128i`) are automatically aligned correctly, but for non-SIMD data types and for dynamic memory allocations (`new`, `malloc`, etc), then you need to take additional care to ensure alignment. If you have data that can not be correctly aligned for some reason then you can use misaligned SIMD loads/stores as a last resort but there is a performance penalty for this.

Comment: why would dynamic memory allocations be of concern? Aren't we only dealing with "primitive" SSE types ("8, 16, 32 and 64 bit integers, and single and double precision floats")?

Comment: Depending on the target platform, dynamic memory allocations may be only 4 or 8 byte aligned. For arrays etc for use with SIMD we typically need 16 byte alignment. You can use e.g. `memalign` or `posix_memalign` on Linux for this. Windows and Mac OS X have similar special-purpose functions. If you need to use C++'s new operator then you'll need a custom allocator.

Comment: @PaulR: On OS X (and iOS), memory returned by the default allocator will always have 16B alignment.

Comment: @PaulR oh sorry, the dynamic memory allocation comes into consideration when the container is declared as such. For statically-allocated containers this would not matter?

Comment: Static allocation is OK if the underlying data type is a SIMD type, e.g. `__m128i`, but if the underlying data type is say `int32_t`, which only has a 4 byte natural alignment, then there is still a problem. I've updated the above answer to illustrate enforcing correct alignment on a non-SIMD array using a GNU extension.

Comment: @Stephen: true - malloc has always been 16 byte aligned on OS X. Linux and WIN32 are typically only 8 byte aligned though.